# Apt-get update fails with debian:stretch altough I referenced archive.debian.org

Tags: linux, debian, docker

So I'm struggling right now, I made a dockerfile and in that dockerfile I run apt-get update, which here doesn't work cause the underlying base distro debian:stretch isn't in the main mirror anymore.
So I got it mostly working with the things I added from research, but I haven't managed to make it completely right.

Does anybody know how I can fix the last few errors I get here, updating to PHP 7.4 isn't an option and also I can't use another underlying base distro other than debian:stretch unless there's a premade docker image for it.

```
FROM php:5.6-apache as dev

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ENV APP_ENV=development

ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

COPY ../. /var/www/xx


RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions
#from research
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian/ stretch-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN echo "deb-src [trusted=yes] http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
#end from research
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install --no-install-recommends apt-utils zip unzip nano ncdu git vim gitg ssh 2>&1
RUN install-php-extensions intl pdo_mysql opcache gd gettext json calendar curl apcu zip
RUN echo "memory_limit = 512M" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "max_execution_time = 600" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo "date.timezone=Europe/Zurich" >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN apt-get autoremove -y
RUN apt-get clean -y
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN rm -rf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
RUN ln -s /var/www/xx/.devcontainer/sites-enabled /etc/apache2/sites-enabled


ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=dialog
```

```bash
#0 3.467 W: The repository 'http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 3.467 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 3.467 W: The repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
#0 3.467 W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org/debian stretch-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 648ACFD622F3D138 NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9
#0 3.467 E: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/debian-security/dists/stretch/updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.2.132 80]
#0 3.467 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 3.467 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/stretch-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
#0 3.467 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only *added* the new archive URLs, but did not remove the old ones.

Add a `true > sources.list` or `rm -f sources.list` before appending the new lines.

Comment: I now feel like an idiot, but ey at least it works, tysm.